# Can you identify this LEGO part? - 8x8 lattice design with 2 studs by 2 studs in the middle

Tags: part-identification

The piece is red 2.5" X 2.5" square, Lattice design with 2 studs by 2 studs solid tile in middle and 8 studs on each outside around the edge

[image: lego piece]

Answer (score 15):

It's 4151 [Plate, Modified 8 x 8 with Grille](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4151). There's a newer variant with a hole, too.

In red, it was in only one set: 6989 [Mega Core Magnetizer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6989-1)

[image: 6989]

Comment: That was definitely one of the sets to gaze at longingly in the catalog as a kid.

Comment: That's a great set too.

Comment: M-Tron was my favorite, I didn't have this one back then, but I think I do now after buying a huge tub used of legos many years ago.

Comment: I'm not that old but I feel the vibe :)